# Connecting to Mongo with replica set and mongo-hadoop connector for Spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pymongo, rdd, replicaset

I have a Spark process that is currently using the mongo-hadoop bridge (from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/spark/src/main/python/README.rst ) to access the mongo database:

```
mongo_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name.collection_name'
mongo_rdd = spark_context.mongoRDD(mongo_url)
```

The mongo instance is now being upgraded to a cluster that can only be accessed with a replica set.

How do I create an RDD using the mongo-hadoop connector?  The mongoRDD() goes to mongoPairRDD(), which may not take multiple strings.

Answer (score 0):

The MongoDB Hadoop Connector `mongoRDD` can take a valid [MongoDB Connection String](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-uri-format).

For example, if it's now a replica set you can specify:

```
mongodb://db1.example.net,db2.example.net:27002,db3.example.net:27003/?db_name&replicaSet=YourReplicaSetName
```

See also related information:

- [mongo-hadoop: Usage with authentication](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Usage-with-Authentication)
- [mongo-hadoop: Configuration Reference](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/wiki/Configuration-Reference#input-and-output-options)